# App uninstalls itself without user intervention. Is it possible?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I'm trying to write a UpdateManager which automatically updates the application. Everything is ready except for the method `RemoveMyself()`.

Question: can app uninstall itself without user intervention?

Comment: If you install a new version of the app - and the new version has exactly the same package/class (`package` attribute of `manifest` element and `android:name` attribute of the main activity) as the old version, it will automatically overwrite the old version with no need to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install a new version of the app - and the new version has exactly the same package/class (package attribute of manifest element and android:name attribute of the main activity) as the old version, it will automatically overwrite the old version with no need to uninstall it.